# Solve the given differential equation $p²-py+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this differential equation for $X$:
$$p²-py+x=0$$
This is how I tried it:
$$Y=p+(\frac{x}{p})$$
Then differentiaing wrt $x$,
$$p=\frac{1}{p}+1-\frac{x}{p²}\frac{dp}{dx}$$
Then
$$\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{(p²-1)p}{p²-x}$$
I can't proceed further. Please help.
Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: is $p=y'$ .....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p^2-py+x=0$$
This is [D'Alembert's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation) :
$$y=xf(p)+g(p)$$
$$y=\dfrac x {p}+p$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$p=\dfrac {p-xp'}{p^2}+p'$$
$$p^3-p=p'(p^2-x)$$
$$p(p^2-1)\dfrac {dx}{dp}=(p^2-x)$$
It's a first order linear DE.
$$p(p^2-1)x'+x=p^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much @aryadeva.. I got it.

Comment: You're welcome @SourajaKundu